# Setting default image programmatically

Tags: image, product-images

I have the following function for auto uploading images and setting the default one:

```
function importImages($sku, $image_url, $is_default){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

    $image_type = substr(strrchr($image_url,"."),1); //find the image extension
    $filename   = md5($image_url . $sku).'.'.$image_type; //give a new name, you can modify as per your requirement
    $filepath   = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import'. DS . $filename; //path for temp storage folder: ./media/import/
    file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents(trim($image_url))); //store the image from external url to the temp storage folder
    if($is_default==true){
        //$product->setMediaGallery(array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
        $mediaAttribute = array (   'image',
                                    'small_image',
                                    'thumbnail'
                                );
    }else{
        $mediaAttribute = null;
    }
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath, $mediaAttribute, true, false);

    $product->save();
}
```

The problem is that the default images isn't setted up as expected.

Comment: its help me : http://www.onlinecode.org/blog/2016/12/19/magento-update-product-image/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experienced that this would not store the images as default images in a multi side store. In order to accomplish this, I had to add the following code after `$product->save();`:

```
$value=$product->getData('small_image');
if ($value) {
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
            ->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), 
                array(
                    'image'=>$value,
                    'small_image'=>$value,
                    'thumbnail'=>$value,
                    ), 
                0);  // 0 specifies the Default
    }
```

Comment: its help me : http://www.onlinecode.org/blog/2016/12/19/magento-update-product-image/

Answer (score 2):

**See the below link for details:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456954/magento-programmatically-add-product-image

Add below code

```
foreach($mediaAttribute as $imageType)
    {
         $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false);
    }
```

to after

```
  $mediaAttribute = array ('image','small_image',                                 'thumbnail'
                );
```

Modified code is

```
$is_default=true;
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

    $image_type = substr(strrchr($image_url,"."),1); //find the image extension
    $filename   = md5($image_url . $sku).'.'.$image_type; //give a new name, you can modify as per your requirement
    $filepath   = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import'. DS . $filename; //path for temp storage folder: ./media/import/
    file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents(trim($image_url))); //store the image from external url to the temp storage folder
    if($is_default==true){
        //$product->setMediaGallery(array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
        $mediaAttribute = array (   'image',
                                    'small_image',
                                    'thumbnail'
                                );
            foreach($mediaAttribute as $imageType)
            {
                 $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false);
            }

    }else{
        $mediaAttribute = null;
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath, $mediaAttribute, true, false);

    }

    $product->save();
```

Comment: Base image is not set using this code. While thumbnail or small image set perfect. Can you please help ?