# Adding generated images to products

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, media

This is similar to [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/37907/1808) question, but I think I understand what I'm trying to do I just don't understand why calling `$product->addImageToMediaGallery` is throwing an error.

I am trying to generate images for products on the fly inside of a `catalog_product_save_before` observer using [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php).  The images are drawn from a custom attribute added to categories (each category's products will each share the same background image) with the product's title written on top and saved.

All of this works currently, I generate the image and right now I am storing it inside of `media/tmp`.  I want to tell Magento to go ahead and generate all of the assorted sizes that product images normally get generated to, and then add *those* images to the product, storing them at the correct place inside of the `media/catalog/product` directory.

As far as I know, calling `$product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false)` will just set the path to the product image at it's current location inside of `media/tmp`, which I don't want.  Is there a particular way to instruct Magento to go ahead and run the thumbnail resize process and move the image to its correct media location?

**Update**

I tried going [this route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540132/697370), and added the following to my observer once the generated image is ready:

```
// Adapted from: @Zachary Schuessler, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540132/697370
// Add three image sizes to media gallery
$mediaArray = array(
    'thumbnail'   => $filename,
    'small_image' => $filename,
    'image'       => $filename,
);

// Remove unset images, add image to gallery if exists
$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'tmp/';

foreach ( $mediaArray as $imageType => $fileName ) {
    $filePath = $importDir . $fileName;
    if ( file_exists($filePath) ) {
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false);
    } 
}
```

When this runs, I can see images being generated inside of `/media/tmp/catalog/product/(a)/(b)`, but when it hits `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php` on line 329, I get an error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`  I look up that line, and it looks like this, inside of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media::addImage`:

```
foreach ($mediaGalleryData['images'] as &$image) {
```

I quickly put in a dump and die statement on the media gallery data:

```
array (size=2)
  'images' => string '[]' (length=2)
  'values' => string '{"image":"no_selection","small_image":"no_selection","thumbnail":"no_selection"}' (length=80)
```

Sure enough, I don't think you can `foreach` over a string like that.  I'm pretty sure my path is right beause the images are being generated correctly in the `media/tmp/catalog/products` directory, but I cant seem to be able to get this `addImageToMediaGallery` call to work the way I think that it should.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this as an answer because it works, though I think my problem is that there is some extension that is modifying these attributes at some point. I haven't really figured out where.

Here is my workaround:

```
// Hack because for some reason the images key in the media gallery is a 
// JSON encoded string instead of an array that 
// Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media::addImage expects
$mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();
$mediaGallery['images'] = json_decode($mediaGallery['images'], true);
$product->setMediaGallery($mediaGallery);
```